# Get dependecy instance from instance with package and name

Tags: java, spring

Let´s say I have instance A, where I have dependencies with instance B and C. B and C also has dependencies with B1 and C1

It would be possible using reflection and the package string as "B.B1" and "C.C1" get those instances from A.

It would be something like

```
          B1 b1 = A.getMagicallyTheInstance("B.B1");
          C1 c1 = A.getMagicallyTheInstance("C.C1");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using java reflection or [OGNL](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-ognl/). OGNL is for object graph notation language and its notation like you want to use. But if you want use reflection you must follow these steps.

1. Get Fields of A
2. Extract B from A's fields and get it as object.
3. Get Fields of B
4. Extract B1 from B's fields and get is as object.
5. Repeat 2-4 for C and C1.

By the way `getResourceAsStream`is for reading class path resources as inputStream. It has noting with reflection as far as I know.

But in OGNL it is a lot simpler.

1. Build a context with existing object. Like an instance of `A`
2. Execute your graph notation by using this context. For get B1 you can use something like "a.b.b1"

And thats all.

### Update

I just realize your Spring tag. You can achieve it using Spring EL easily. Here is an example:

```
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();
    Expression exp = parser.parseExpression("b.b1");
    // I Assume A has a field name b, and B has a field name b1
    B1 b1 = (B1) exp.getValue(aInsantece);
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by bhdrkn, OGNL is probably the way to go.

However if you'd like to use plain reflection you can do something like this:

```
Container instance = new Container();
Class<? extends Container> klass = instance.getClass();
Field field = klass.getField("value");
String actualValue = (String) field.get(instance);
```

where Container looks like this:

```
public class Container {
    public String value = "default";
}
```

Comment: I modify the explanation, I want the instance not the class to create a new instance

Comment: I think bhdrkn's answer is probably what you're looking for.